# Redirect URL with GET variable to site with the GET variable in it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect, for example :

```
index.php?name=sarah
```

to

```
names/sarah.php
```

The folder structure:

- names/...
- index.php

I've tried :

```
RewriteRule index.php?name=$1 /names/$1.php
```

and other ones, but didn't came to a solution.

Is this possible? If so, how can you do this?

---

**Note**:

The other way round is

```
RewriteRule ^names/([^/]*)\.php$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /names/%1.php?
```

Answer (score 1):

You first example wont work as you are trying to  manipulate query strings using a RewriteRule but this is not allowed. You  can try the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} / index\.php\?q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /names/%1.php? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^names/([^/]*)\.php$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```